# XYZ Distance point-to-point of two glm::mat4 matrices

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have two glm::mat4 modelview matrices and I need to compare the distance between the two xyz points, I tried this code but it doesnt seem to be accurate;

```
inline GLfloat Dist3D(GLfloat X1, GLfloat Y1, GLfloat Z1,
    GLfloat X2, GLfloat Y2, GLfloat Z2) {
    return sqrt(pow((X2 - X1), 2) + pow((Y2 - Y1), 2) + pow((Z2 - Z1), 2));
}
void PlayerScore::CompareMatrixes(
    glm::mat4 Target,
    glm::mat4 Source) {

    GLfloat dist = Dist3D(
        Target[3][0], Target[3][1], Target[3][2],
        Source[3][0], Source[3][1], Source[3][2]);

    printf("Dist to target %f\n", dist);
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you using, what result do you get, and what result do you expect?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ive got a recorded set of hands that ran from controllers in a vr game with recorded matrices that determine their position and ive got the matrices for my current hands and when i put them together in the game while looking at the console i expect the number to get lower as the hands get closer but the number goes lower a bit as i get closer but when i get really close it stops getting lower and goes higher

Comment: Concerning your actual issue, your code looks correct to me. (May be, I justice this with certain assumptions about your ModelView matrices.) _I tried this code but it doesnt seem to be accurate_. isn't a that precise issue description. You could expose sample values for `Target` and `Source` (dump the _whole_ matrix to show whether it really does contain translation (with w = 1) and rotation only), the distance you expect to see and the one you got instead.

Comment: OT.: Instead of `pow(x, 2)`, I would always prefer `x * x`. In your case, you could make another little helper `GLfloat sqr(GLfloat x) { return x * x; }`. I simply forgot what pow() actually does but definitely more than one simple multiplication... (Though, concerning precision, replacing `pow()` would be a win, IMHO.)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks that really clears it up, there are heaps of matrices, hmd movement /lookat base and per eye, keyboard/touchpad movement/lookat, controller movement, target is(was) a keyboard view matrix and a model from the head to the controller and source was a previous version of it, really way too much to post but there recorded as w=1's, looks like im back to the drawing board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `glm::length` to determine the distance between two points.

```
glm::vec3 v1 = {2.0, 0.0, 0.0};
glm::vec3 v2 = {6.0, 0.0, 0.0};

auto distance = glm::length(v2 - v1);

std::cout << distance << std::endl; // expected output is 4

glm::mat4 identity(1.0);

glm::mat4 m1 = glm::translate(identity, v1);
glm::mat4 m2 = glm::translate(identity, v2);

// note that the operator[] returns an entire column as vec4
distance = glm::length(m2[3] - m1[3]);

std::cout << distance << std::endl; // expected output is 4
```